# ASP.NET Filter Expression

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Hi I'm trying to get a filter expression working on my content column located in BLOG table on my gridview. 
It displays the content column fine with 50 characters but when i try click my asp button to run the filter expression i get an error saying content column not found.
Any idea why this is?

Here's my code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Assignment2ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [blogid], [myfriendid], [inputdate], 
Left(content,50) FROM [BLOG]" filterexpression="[content] LIKE '%{0}%' or url LIKE '%{0}%'">

   <filterparameters>
  <asp:controlparameter controlid="TextBox1" propertyname="Text" />
  </filterparameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `Left(content,50)` that the column no longer has a name

Change the to this

```
ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:Assignment2ConnectionString %>"     
selectCommand  "SELECT [blogid], [myfriendid], [inputdate], 
               Left(content,50) AS ShortContent FROM [BLOG]" 
filterexpression = "[ShortContent] LIKE '%{0}%' or url LIKE '%{0}%'">
```